# Collection error in meteor.js

Tags: meteor

I'm learning meteor from  the book [Your First Application](http://files.meteortips.com/book.pdf) and I'm stuck at *4.2 Create a Collection*. When I refresh my web page this come out:

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.
Hello world!
/home/krtolica/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: A method named '/players/insert' is already defined
    at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1444:1
    at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
    at [object Object]._.extend.methods (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1442:1)
    at [object Object].Mongo.Collection._defineMutationMethods (packages/mongo/collection.js:886:1)
    at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:208:1)
    at app/leaderboard.js:3:15
    at app/leaderboard.js:13:3
    at /home/krtolica/Meteor/leaderboard/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:205:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/krtolica/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1ef5dzv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-**lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: could you please put the server file?

Comment: You've defined `Mongo.Collection("players")` twice

Comment: console.log("Hello world!");
new Mongo.Collection('players');
PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
 
}

Comment: Get rid of the extra `new Mongo.Collection('players');`  I think you should try a codeacademy javascript lesson before you do this, you are missing significant understanding of basic programming and what code does.

Comment: @Akshat Please post it as an answer for the goodness of the people of the unknown future!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, it seems  you need to wrap the **Template.form** definition *inside* a **Meteor.isClient** condition, like this:

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
    Template.leaderboard.helpers({
    "player": function(){
    return "doesn't work!"
   }
 });
}
```